# Angular 2 throw error of array undefined when trying to push data

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on Angular2 component in which I have declare array of string and initialise same time, in this component, in one of method I trying to push data but getting error of undefined, not sure what I am missing here!

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

    public categoryData: string[] = [];

    ngOnInit(): void {

    }

    public loadDataFromServer() {

        let MyServerData = result.data;

        MyServerData.forEach(function (item) {
            this.categoryData.push(item.BarTitle); // error here
        });
    }
}
```

### error

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'categoryData' of undefined
```

Comment: Inirtialize the array: `categoryData = []`

Comment: Try an arrow function: `MyServerData.forEach(item => { ... })`

Comment: I believe categoryData:string[] = []; by doing =[] so or not?

Comment: no still error ............

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use This code It will Work:

```js
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

public categoryData:string[] = [];

ngOnInit(): void {

}

 public loadDataFromServer() {

        let MyServerData = result.data;
        const crntData = this;
        MyServerData .forEach(function(item){
            crntData.categoryData.push(item.BarTitle); // error here
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: this worked ... thanks ... i don't know why someone give you negative marking!

Comment: @khurram he got downvotes because the year isn't 2014....

Answer (score 4):

You have to use an arrow function, or you lose the `this` context to the new anonymous function created with the `function` keyword:

```
MyServerData.forEach((item) => {
  this.categoryData.push(item.BarTitle); // no error here
});
```

Comment: no ... still got error

Comment: @khurram that's probably because you didn't copy my answer correctly, and are still using the `function` keyword in the `forEach` callback

Comment: Anyway, this question has already been asked and answered so many times on the Angular forum. It is the ultimate duplicate question.

Comment: @ConnorsFan yep, also very difficult to search for, because the error is always different :)